# Language changing button on the left of the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small web app which looks like this [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EBBy.png)

Here is also a link to the sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-kalam-v1lpg)

All page fieldnames are loaded from a single dictionary. The question is: how to change this page language on button-click (reload it from another dictionary)? Preferably the button should be on the top-left corner of the page (not of the form)

Comment: please upload your code on stack overflow, do not give us link to your code, more than that, you litterally give us the project like hey find the problem inside my project. Show us what you tried and try to identify where you want a solution on your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire application in `React.Context` that holds the current language and return the dictionary of translated strings from the custom hook according to the selected language key. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-violet-lh886?file=/src/App.js) is a quick example.